# how to resize an image stream from mongo gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ffmpeg, gridfs

i'm still new to node so bear with me.

i have images stored in mongo gridfs.  how do i resize the image stream?  i'm trying to use ffmpeg.  here's my method:

```
exports.read = function (req, res) {
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var id = new ObjectID(req.params.imageId);
var store = new GridStore(db, id, 'r', {root: 'fs'});

store.open(function (err, store) {
    if (err) return err;

    res.header("Content-Type", store.metadata['Content Type']);
    res.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + store.filename + "'");

    new ffmpeg()
        .input(store.stream(true))
        .size('650x365')
        .output('/temp/screenshot.png')
        .run();

    store.stream(true).pipe(res)
});
};
```

but i'm getting an error:

Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're piping a `GridStore` stream to `res` before `ffmpeg` can finish running, which could cause all kinds of unpredictable results. Also, the stream that you're piping to `res` is the from your `GridStore` and not the output from `ffmpeg`. So, even if `ffmpeg` did run correctly, you'd end up getting the original image and not the resized one.

It's been a while since I've used `GridStore` and `ffmpeg` so I'm a little rusty, but I took a quick look at the docs and I think you want something like this:

***Note:** I'm assuming you're using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)*

```
store.open(function (err, store) {
    if (err) return err; // !! NOTE: This return won't do anything... you should handle the error condition differently !!

    res.header("Content-Type", store.metadata['Content Type']);
    res.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + store.filename + "'");

    ffmpeg() // You shouldn't need "new" here
        .input(store.stream(true))
        .size('650x365')
        .pipe(res);
});
```

That code is streaming the output from `ffmpeg` directly to `res` which eliminates the need for the temporary file and simplifies things quite a bit.

***Note:** I don't recommend taking this approach on anything but a prototype or extremely low traffic site. The overhead of resizing the image on each request is going to be large; you should be caching the resized image and returning that.*

Comment: thanks Mike S.  i'm still prototyping and trying to figure things out.  thanks again for your advice.